# I can't get scale_x_discrete(limits) to reorder my axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

hslresto <- read.delim("HSL_Resto.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
hslrestomelted <- melt(hslresto, id.vars = c("HSL"))

colnames(hslrestomelted)
colnames(hslrestomelted) <- c("HSL", "Treatment", "Index")

HSLplot <- ggplot(hslrestomelted, aes(HSL, Index, fill=Treatment)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), show.legend = TRUE,scale_x_discrete(limits=c("Control", "10 mM C6", "100 mM C6", "1000 mM C6", "10 mM C10", "100 mM C10", "1000 mM C10")))


HSLplot
```

I would like my x-axis to be displayed in the order that I outlined in scale_x_discrete, but it is instead showing in alphanumerical order (1000 mM C10, 1000 mM C6, 100 mM C10,.... Control). I'm sure this is just a simple issue with either where I placed the scale_x_discrete code, or my x axis isn't considered discrete, but since I'm new to R, I cant figure it out. I also tried moving it outside of the initial code, so it read:

```
HSLplot<- ggplot(hslrestomelted, aes(HSL, Index, fill=Treatment)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), show.legend = TRUE)
HSLplot + scale_x_discrete(limits=c("Control", "10 mM C6", "100 mM C6", "1000 mM C6", "10 mM C10", "100 mM C10", "1000 mM C10"))
HSLplot
```

and that also didn't work. Can I get some help in figuring this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you convert HSL to a factor (specifying the levels) it will plot the way you want.  For example:

```
levs <- c("Control", "10 mM C6", "100 mM C6", "1000 mM C6", "10 mM C10", "100 mM C10", "1000 mM C10")

hslrestomelted$HSL <- factor(hslrestomelted$HSL, levels = lev)
```

Then try plotting without `scale_x_discrete()`.

Comment: You may also need `ordered=TRUE` as parameter to `factor` to always maintain the sequence